# Static .lib required for compiling library is also required for library users?

Tags: haskell, dll, static-libraries, cabal, cabal-install

I've been working on a Haskell library package which requires a custom .dll and .lib on Windows to talk to some OS APIs. The .lib is linked into the library with the `extra-libraries` field and the DLL is installed in the cabal package directory with `data-files`.

For some reason (I'm not an expert on linking by any means, but this seems weird) if I create a test executable which uses my package (in the `build-depends` field), it wants to link in the same .lib used to compile the library - even though it's just calling library functions, not anything the .lib exposes. Obviously it needs access to the .dll at runtime but that is to be expected. Needing the .lib as well seems odd.

I would expect that the .lib would already be linked into the .a file generated by Cabal/GHC for my library when it's installed. Is this not the case? And if it is, can someone explain why it's that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want partial linking (see `--relocatable` flag in `ld` manual page). As I can see from the sources, `cabal` uses partial linking only libraries, compiled for `ghci`. From [Distribution.Simple.GHC](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/GHC.hs) (`buildLib` function):

```
whenVanillaLib False $ do
  (arProg, _) <- requireProgram verbosity arProgram (withPrograms lbi)
  Ar.createArLibArchive verbosity arProg
    vanillaLibFilePath staticObjectFiles

whenProfLib $ do
  (arProg, _) <- requireProgram verbosity arProgram (withPrograms lbi)
  Ar.createArLibArchive verbosity arProg
    profileLibFilePath profObjectFiles

whenGHCiLib $ do
  (ldProg, _) <- requireProgram verbosity ldProgram (withPrograms lbi)
  Ld.combineObjectFiles verbosity ldProg
    ghciLibFilePath ghciObjFiles

whenSharedLib False $
  runGhcProg ghcSharedLinkArgs
```

You can see, that for vanilla and profiling libraries, `cabal` just calls `ar` utility (see [createArLibArchive](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/Program/Ar.hs)). For `ghci` it calls `ld` with `-r` flag (which is a shortcut for `--relocatable`) (see [combineObjectFiles](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/Program/Ld.hs)).

So, `cabal` doesn't actually do any linking for vanilla libraries, it just combines object files. Actually `cabal` can't know, whether final application will use any symbol from your `extra-lib`, so the behavior seems reasonable.

Comment: Is there a way to force it to use `ld -r` instead of `ar` for vanilla libraries? I've tried adding `ld-options: -r` but it doesn't seem to do anything (presumably because `ld` isn't being used?)

Comment: @TomSavage No, I think it is not possible. But I'm not an expert in cabal.